# Angularjs regex case insensitive modifier not working

Tags: angularjs, regex

**Update:**
 Could the issue be with the way I tested this? 
I tested this by making a change in the browser (through Developer Tools), changed the ng-pattern, and expected the validation to go through.
Maybe the code changes (in the browser) aren't being picked up, that is, re-evaluation not being done?

I am trying to use the below Email Address pattern in http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

```
\A[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z
```

My code:

```
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/" id="email-1" value="" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern">
```

This is case sensitive. I tried using 'i' modifier.

```
"/^[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/i"
```

However, it still wouldn't accept capitalized character (shows invalid email error message).

I came across https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1437. However, I am using a later version (1.2).

I also tried A-Z, no luck with that either.

```
"/^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$/"
```

How to make this pattern case insensitive?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think the problem is not with your regex pattern. [I've tested the pattern and seems to work just fine](https://regex101.com/r/8tSW7k/1).

Comment: Thank you @Casper! I thought as much, at least "/^[A-Za-z0-9..." should have worked. I added more information (please see the 'Update').

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, the issue turned out to be the way I tested. 
"/i" worked.
"/i" didn't work when I tested by editing the code (added "/i") through browser. However, worked when I made the code change (in the corresponding html/javascript file).
Makes me wonder why such change in browser wasn't picked up.